# Bootstrap tabs not working inside modal in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have walked through similar questions asked by others but no answer seems to apply to my code. I have one modal instance that is opened from the main controller. It is based on the following HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Add media</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="min-height:auto;">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabContent">
        <li class="active">
            <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#urlTab" href="">URL</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#filesTab" href="">Upload files</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="urlTab" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <form name="form.URLForm" class="form-group">                                
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="filesTab" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
            <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="form.URLForm.$invalid">Add</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The code that triggers the modal is the following:

```
$scope.openUploadMediaModal = function ($event) {
            $event.stopPropagation();

            modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                backdrop: 'static',
                templateUrl: 'properUrl',
                controller: 'ModalCtrl',
                scope: $scope,
                resolve: {
                    files: function () {
                        return $scope.files;
                    }
                }
            }).result.then(function (media) {
                //something
            });
        }
```

Switching tabs is not working and I have no idea why. Everything I have on the first tab is functioning properly so, apparently, there is no problem with the controller or the dependencies. What else could it be?

Thank you very, very much!

Comment: How your making the model pop up visible ? Are you dynamically adding model html ?

Comment: I have added that code

Comment: remove `type="submit"` attribute from `<button>` within pop-up

Answer (score 0):

just Remove the `href=""` attribute  from anchor tag ( `<a>`) its work sucessfully